# Numpy invalid value encountered in sign

Tags: python, numpy

Hi so there is a weird invalid value encountered error. So I have tried to debug it using some print statements. I have attached the code, error and the debug output where it crashes.

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikD9k.jpg)

[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vv86.png)

[The print statements at the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcaaW.png)

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide your code inline as well as have your errors be inline text as well. That is the preferred method of StackOverflow - there can often be issues with screenshots over time

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).